# Loop through all but one Worksheet and copy select Rows with text reference

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I already found the code below to copy a certain row in a new worksheet, but i can´t manage to loop this through all worksheets except "Consolidate". The remaining Worksheets are numbered 1-40.

Do you guys have an idea?

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strLastRow As String
Dim rngC As Range
Dim strToFind As String, FirstAddress As String
Dim wSht As Worksheet
Dim rngtest As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wSht = Worksheets("1")
strToFind = InputBox("Enter Search Criteria")
With wSht.Range("A:A")
Set rngC = .Find(what:=strToFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not rngC Is Nothing Then
FirstAddress = rngC.Address
Do
strLastRow = Sheets("Consolidate").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
rngC.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Consolidate").Cells(strLastRow, 1)
Set rngC = .FindNext(rngC)
Loop While Not rngC Is Nothing And rngC.Address <> FirstAddress
End If
End With
MsgBox ("Finished")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strLastRow As String
Dim rngC As Range
Dim strToFind As String, FirstAddress As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngtest As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strToFind = InputBox("Enter Search Criteria")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'loops through all the sheets
If ws.name <> "Consolidate" Then ' everyone except consolidate
With ws.Range("A:A") ' searches by your criteria
Set rngC = .Find(what:=strToFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not rngC Is Nothing Then
FirstAddress = rngC.Address
Do
strLastRow = Sheets("Consolidate").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
rngC.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Consolidate").Cells(strLastRow, 1)
Set rngC = .FindNext(rngC)
Loop While Not rngC Is Nothing And rngC.Address <> FirstAddress
End If
End With
End If
Next ws ' next sheet

MsgBox ("Finished")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strLastRow As String
Dim rngC As Range
Dim strToFind As String, FirstAddress As String
Dim wSht As Worksheet
Dim rngtest As String

dim i as integer' used to iterate through all worksheets in your workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
for i = 1 to Worksheets.count' i.e. will give you the number of worksheets in your workbook

    'Set wSht = Worksheets("1")    
    Set wSht = Worksheets(i)'take "control" of the worksheet i
    if lcase(wSht.name) <> "consolidation" then

    strToFind = InputBox("Enter Search Criteria")
    With wSht.Range("A:A")
    Set rngC = .Find(what:=strToFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not rngC Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddress = rngC.Address
    Do
        strLastRow = Sheets("Consolidate").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        rngC.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Consolidate").Cells(strLastRow, 1)
        Set rngC = .FindNext(rngC)
    Loop While Not rngC Is Nothing And rngC.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
    End With
    end if
next i
MsgBox ("Finished")


end sub
```